# Azure IoT Edge computing with CNTK

Tags: nvidia, cntk

Followed Build 2017 this week and I got very exited about **[Azure IoT Edge computing](https://blogs.microsoft.com/firehose/2017/05/10/build-2017-learn-about-edge-computing-and-azure-iot-edge/#sm.00018jkenn4rqey7ybm2ht3z1dytu)** and the **[AI for the workplace](https://thenextweb.com/dd/2017/05/10/microsofts-wicked-smart-camera-ai-tracks-people-equipment-keep-workers-safe/#.tnw_yVzCSwPJ)** demo.
How do I do this with CNTK. What's the best IoT board I can use?
When CNTK will run on NVIDIA Jetson TX2?

Comment: Azure IoT Edge is now in public preview: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-iot-edge-works

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to run CNTK model evaluation/inferrence on edge devices. We have prototype running CNTK Eval on a couple of ARM64 board like PINE64 and Qualcomm 410C dragonboard with 64bit Linux. According to specification of NVIDIA Jetson TX2, it should be technically feasible to run CNTK on it. However, we have not tried to run on it. As the card has a GPU, it should be even possible to run CNTK GPU version on it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I'll compile for  NVIDIA Jetson TX2 when CNTK is released in June.